# Determine if $f(x)=1_{\mathbb{Q}}-1_{\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}}$ is Borel

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

I want to determine if the following function is Borel:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1, \, x\in \mathbb Q\\ 
-1, \, x \notin \mathbb Q
\end{cases}$$

My idea is that:
$$f^{1}(1)=[Q_1] \bigcup [Q_2] \bigcup ... [Q_n]$$
and
$$f^{-1}(-1)=(a,b) \bigcup (b,c) \bigcup ... (d,e)$$
for the irrationals

However I am not sure about the last part because I need to mathematically show that these are only the irrationals

Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: Hint. Show that the rationals are Borel. And use that to show the irrationals are Borel as well. Remember that the Borel sigma-algebra contains all the closed sets and is closed under *countable* unions and complementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That last part is not OK, because no matter what $a,b$ are, there is always some rational in the interval (so long as the interval is not empty)

However, you can more simply write $$f^{-1}(-1) = \left(f^{-1}(1)\right)^c.$$

Comment: Nice way of expressing it

Answer (score 1):

$f=1_{\Bbb{Q}}+(-1)1_{\Bbb{Q}^c}$

Note the $f$ is a sum of Borel measurable functions because $\Bbb{Q}$ is a countable union of closed sets and $\Bbb{Q}^c$ is an countable intersection of open sets.

So both sets are Borel,and thus their indicator functions are Borel measurable.